# Counting values in data frame rows against another df to see how many values are higher

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames

- df2022fl One is a list of 24 rows
- df One is one row of values

1759 columns in each df.

I want to reference every row in dataframe with 24 rows too count how many columns are above the corresponding column in the one row df.

I used the code below, but keep getting the error below the line of code

```
( df2022fl > df.T[df2022fl.columns].values ).sum(axis=1) 


KeyError: "None of [Index(['id', 'table_position', 'performance_rank', 'risk', 'competition_id',\n       'suspended_matches', 'homeAttackAdvantage', 'homeDefenceAdvantage',\n       'homeOverallAdvantage', 'seasonGoals_overall',\n       ...\n       'freekicks_total_over275_away', 'freekicks_total_over285_overall',\n       'freekicks_total_over285_home', 'freekicks_total_over285_away',\n       'freekicks_total_over295_overall', 'freekicks_total_over295_home',\n       'freekicks_total_over295_away', 'freekicks_total_over305_overall',\n       'freekicks_total_over305_home', 'freekicks_total_over305_away'],\n      dtype='object', length=1759)] are in the [columns]"
```

I have no idea why this is happening as I removed all type object also, to have just float64 dtypes

Any ideas to help please?

df in text format, this is the dataframe with one row

```
234 5   5   42  32  0   4   -33 -2  54  30  84  55  29  54  31  19  30  20  10  35  31  34  56  49  58  74  71  71  3   4   -4  16  8   7   13  5   6   7   3   4   38  19  19  4   3   3   1   13  5   5   28  26  21  22  10  9   48  50  39  10  23  9   13  2   3   19  50  42  42  9   10  18  10  6   47  42  32  6   2   2   13  9   9   1   1   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   35  35  30  27  26  25  18  13  21  10  6   2   21  26  8   8   8   17  35  33  39  2   3   8   9   16  17  51  26  17  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   20  12  7   16  7   5   37  19  14  -8  -2  -9  0   3   5   14  27  34  0   8   13  37  60  81  96  85  67  44  26  4   37  35  32  21  11  2   0   8   25  48  67  79  0   2   5   11  16  18  92  78  65  37  16  0   18  16  14  7   3   0   0   0   0   11  50  83  0   0   0   2   11  16  92  83  67  48  21  4   19  19  16  11  5   1   1   8   24  3   17  52  4   25  48  1   6   11  0   9   57  0   2   12  38  19  19  25  25  22  15  14  9   5   3   2   66  64  49  39  36  19  13  8   4   12  12  9   6   5   3   1   1   1   63  63  47  32  26  16  5   5   5   13  13  12  9   9   4   3   2   0   68  63  50  46  39  17  13  9   0   31  24  19  13  8   5   2   82  63  50  34  21  13  5   16  14  11  6   3   2   1   84  74  56  32  16  11  4   15  10  8   7   5   2   1   78  53  42  37  26  9   5   26  21  15  10  5   3   2   57  47  32  21  11  6   4   12  9   3   2   1   0   0   52  41  14  9   5   0   0   14  12  9   6   2   1   0   61  52  38  25  8   4   0   37  34  25  18  12  4   2   0   0   94  81  57  46  28  8   4   0   0   18  15  11  8   5   1   1   0   0   88  74  46  39  21  4   4   0   0   19  19  14  10  5   3   1   0   0   96  83  63  42  26  13  4   0   0   29  19  7   2   0   0   0   75  40  15  4   0   0   0   12  8   3   2   0   0   0   63  33  13  8   0   0   0   17  10  4   0   0   0   0   83  42  17  0   0   0   0   33  21  11  5   0   0   0   77  55  25  11  0   0   0   17  10  4   2   0   0   0   71  46  17  8   0   0   0   16  11  4   1   0   0   0   83  57  21  4   0   0   0   5   6   2   7   7   14  30  29  30  176 91  85  66  27  35  8   8   9   4   4   4   161 63  94  3   3   3   10  0   4   0   1   1   1   374 229 145 9   12  7   177 88  75  197 127 70  4   4   3   5   6   3   48  51  46  9   9   8   377 182 195 151 66  79  62  28  31  32  16  16  3   2   3   1   1   1   32  31  27  19  12  6   4   96  78  59  41  26  13  9   16  15  12  7   5   1   1   96  78  52  30  22  4   4   16  16  14  10  7   4   1   96  75  57  46  28  17  4   30  18  4   1   0   0   0   78  38  9   2   0   0   0   16  9   0   0   0   0   0   78  39  0   0   0   0   0   14  9   4   1   0   0   0   75  38  17  4   0   0   0   8   4   3   17  17  13  38  19  19  6   4   1   13  17  5   7   3   3   15  13  13  1   1   0   3   5   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   46  31  15  14  9   5   32  19  10  4   10  26  11  26  67  3   7   14  13  37  70  0   3   12  0   16  63  57  33  24  1   1   1   14  8   5   30  35  22  14  5   9   33  26  39  5   2   3   13  11  13  0   2   0   6   4   2   16  21  9   6   2   2   13  9   9   18  9   9   39  39  39  17  6   10  38  26  42  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   2   3   3   1   3   4   4   3   6   3   5   1   5   4   8   2   5   5   5   7   7   10  7   10  11  9   9   16  13  12  16  3   4   5   7   9   11  5   3   6   5   3   5   1   1   0   2   3   2   4   3   4   1   1   2   4   5   6   0   0   0   1   0   2   0   2   1   2   1   2   2   1   3   1   2   0   4   6   7   5   6   5   3   2   9   9   9   9   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   1   2   0   0   3   2   1   3   1   2   0   2   1   1   0   0   1   2   1   2   2   1   1   2   2   1   3   1   3   2   2   6   3   3   7   4   3   7   42  0   0   0   0   0   0   -2  -1  -1  -2  -1  -1  1   5   17  28  2   11  37  67  1   3   9   15  4   13  39  65  0   1   6   12  0   5   28  56  0   1   5   24  0   3   13  63  0   1   5   13  0   4   21  54  0   0   0   10  0   0   0   53  37  18  19  38  19  19  44  21  21  92  44  48  19  8   7   40  19  20  22  11  11  47  23  22  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   2   2   2   50  52  48  23  22  25  0   0   0   27  27  21  40  28  39  15  9   18  14  11  9   56  52  61  34  36  25  50  43  56  66  27  35  73  38  34  1   1   1   1   1   1   139 66  73  3   2   3   4   1   1   3   1   1   3   1   1   0   0   0   38  19  19  10  11  9   3   5   3   2   3   6   4   1   12  8   7   4   8   5   5   3   4   2   2   1   31  21  16  9   42  25  23  14  17  9   9   4   19  16  13  5   4   3   11  9   4   42  36  28  23  18  14  57  47  21  19  13  11  8   4   4   13  11  9   7   7   7   6   2   2   1   1   1   50  34  28  21  11  11  61  56  47  37  37  37  32  11  9   5   5   5   28  18  12  6   11  7   5   2   13  7   3   1   62  40  31  13  50  32  23  9   68  37  16  5   1   0   1   32  15  17  1   0   0   2   0   4   78  74  74  2   0   0   4   1   2   0   0   0   1   0   0   8   4   11  0   0   0   2   0   0   32  16  16  350 172 178 10  10  11  23  27  20  6   9   21  13  8   13  26  17  4   2   5   6   7   2   2   0   0   0   1   1   3   2   0   0   0   1   4   3   1   0   0   0   0   38  19  19  10  8   1   1   1   0   26  35  5   2   4   0   0   0   0   3   1   0   26  11  13  6   4   1   7   3   3   10  7   3   12  3   5   15  13  13  22  13  25  13  21  0   0   0   7   4   0   57  48  54  15  17  4   30  6   6   6   2   2   3   9   10  7   18  12  6   0   0   0   0   0   0   41  52  30  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   2   7   2   3   17  8   13  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

df2022fl below why is the 24 rows dataframe

Comment: can you share the data in the text format please

Comment: Hi Himanshu, I can but its a lot of characters so won't let me post easily. Is there are way to upload the file do you know pls?

Comment: can you upload on drive and share the link please

Comment: thanks. I've added the row from df, which is the values I want to compare df2022fl 24 rows too

Comment: does not help, we need the dataframe post on drive share link

Comment: df = https://stackoverflowtez.filecloudonline.com/url/2dqsbh3wgywuip3e                         df2022fl = https://stackoverflowtez.filecloudonline.com/url/dinqsuubrzzym6xm.        It hasn't added column names though, which probably doesn't help?

Comment: what is this, the data is so weird, contains text in between, unqeual column length `c/\data\np.txt` does not make sense at all

Comment: Do this `df2022fl.to_csv("file1.csv")` and `df.csv("diledf.csv")`

Comment: df2022fl - https://stackoverflowtez.filecloudonline.com/url/6yjyfzyjegsnhaks.          df - https://stackoverflowtez.filecloudonline.com/url/yjziw3qch4cidmqu.                   The other was a np.txt yes I did think it wasn't help, sorry.

Comment: and the second dataframe?

Comment: both in the comment now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare both the dataframe using

```
df2022fl.ge(df.iloc[0]).sum()
```

This gives us the number of values in df2022fl which is greater than the value in df

**Output :**

```
id                                 24
table_position                     20
performance_rank                   20
risk                               23
competition_id                     24
                                   ..
freekicks_total_over295_home       24
freekicks_total_over295_away       24
freekicks_total_over305_overall    24
freekicks_total_over305_home       24
freekicks_total_over305_away       24
Length: 1759, dtype: int64
```

To get the number of column which came out to be greater than the values in dataframe `df` you can use axis = 1.

```
df2022fl['stats'] = df2022fl.ge(df.iloc[0]).sum(axis=1)
```

This gives you expected output :

```
        id  table_position  ...  freekicks_total_over305_away  stats
1    234.0             6.0  ...                           0.0   1688
2    235.0            18.0  ...                           0.0   1529
3    236.0            16.0  ...                           0.0   1565
4    237.0            24.0  ...                           0.0   1409
5    242.0             3.0  ...                           0.0   1566
6    244.0             4.0  ...                           0.0   1681
7    246.0            23.0  ...                           0.0   1607
8    247.0             5.0  ...                           0.0   1642
9    248.0            14.0  ...                           0.0   1603
10   253.0            15.0  ...                           0.0   1575
11   254.0            12.0  ...                           0.0   1554
12   255.0            13.0  ...                           0.0   1593
13   257.0            20.0  ...                           0.0   1533
14   258.0            21.0  ...                           0.0   1537
15   259.0             9.0  ...                           0.0   1585
16   262.0            17.0  ...                           0.0   1488
17   265.0            11.0  ...                           0.0   1647
18   267.0             7.0  ...                           0.0   1628
19   268.0             2.0  ...                           0.0   1615
20  1020.0             1.0  ...                           0.0   1601
21  1827.0             8.0  ...                           0.0   1603
22  1833.0            22.0  ...                           0.0   1587
23  3124.0            19.0  ...                           0.0   1594
24  3141.0            10.0  ...                           0.0   1623
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it gives the same answer as above. What I require though is a count for each row vs each individual column, to see which row is greater than the most in df.

Comment: or may be I didn't get you, can you post the expected output please

Comment: Understood, I'm quite new to this. For each 24 rows, there will be an added column in the df2022fl. Called stat count. This is a count of how many of that given row in df2022fl was greater than the corresponding column in df. So for example homeAttackAdvantage column, any row in df2022fl that is higher than 4.0 in df will get a 1 added to count, repeat this for every column. To see which row is greater in the most stats. Does this make sense?

Comment: I can see there are a few stats with 24 teams/rows higher, this means they would all get +1 added to count, any team not higher for the given stat/coloumn wouldn't get added to there count/tally. Just want to see which row was higher in the most stats

Comment: Can you check my answer now, and let me know if that helps?

Comment: It worked, thanks. Appreciate the patience and help shown. Very nice of you.